# Problem with Memory Management in Android image processing with http protocol

Tags: android, http, memory-management, image-processing

I have a problem with a memory management. I'm downloading some data through mine HTTP client. Next thing I want to display data to the user.
The problem is not stable, on some files of the same type it occurs, on some not. Stable thing is, that it is occurring on the same file.

Here is LogCat input.

Technically I have no clue what to do next. I tried, starting gc in the specific threads with no effect.

If you need more data, please let me know.

```
10-06 16:23:26.281: DEBUG/pecman(2035): szPath - http://demo.pecman.net/webdav/xbUxVPxnRme17FKS898BTCtEtRJUY/CGxrTVdeRssGWjMlCfEElJmA==/P1000887.JPG
10-06 16:23:26.281: DEBUG/pecman(2035): szMime - image/jpeg
10-06 16:23:26.422: INFO/ActivityManager(1277): Displayed activity com.verdandsky.pecman/.MediaPlayerActivity: 380 ms (total 380 ms)
10-06 16:23:27.023: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 1962 objects / 388136 bytes in 102ms
10-06 16:23:27.023: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(2035): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.314MB for 519160-byte allocation
10-06 16:23:27.086: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 37 objects / 1544 bytes in 64ms
10-06 16:23:27.648: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 38 objects / 259232 bytes in 82ms
10-06 16:23:27.750: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(2035): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.022MB for 1052024-byte allocation
10-06 16:23:27.844: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 89ms
10-06 16:23:28.492: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 6 objects / 519312 bytes in 103ms
10-06 16:23:28.805: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(2035): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.544MB for 2116208-byte allocation
10-06 16:23:28.898: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 92ms
10-06 16:23:29.063: DEBUG/AudioHardwareMot(1055): AudioMgr:AudioStreamOutMot::standby called
10-06 16:23:29.063: DEBUG/AudioHardwareMot(1055): AudioMgr:Output 0xb538 entering standby
10-06 16:23:29.071: DEBUG/AudioHardwareMot(1055): AudioMgr:Closing stereo device
10-06 16:23:30.351: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 46 objects / 1054384 bytes in 99ms
10-06 16:23:30.390: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(2035): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.585MB for 4242456-byte allocation
10-06 16:23:30.453: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 61ms
10-06 16:23:32.328: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 9 objects / 2118544 bytes in 53ms
10-06 16:23:32.375: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 2 objects / 48 bytes in 49ms
10-06 16:23:32.390: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(2035): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.019MB for 3622512-byte allocation
10-06 16:23:32.469: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 82ms
10-06 16:23:32.531: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 60ms
10-06 16:23:32.945: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(2035): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.474MB for 3622512-byte allocation
10-06 16:23:33.062: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 120ms
10-06 16:23:33.062: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(2035): 14155776-byte external allocation too large for this process.
10-06 16:23:33.062: ERROR/(2035): VM won't let us allocate 14155776 bytes
10-06 16:23:33.062: DEBUG/skia(2035): --- decoder->decode returned false
10-06 16:23:33.117: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 6 objects / 7245192 bytes in 50ms
10-06 16:23:33.164: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 2 objects / 48 bytes in 49ms
10-06 16:23:33.172: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(2035): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.020MB for 3622512-byte allocation
10-06 16:23:33.258: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 80ms
10-06 16:23:33.320: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 63ms
10-06 16:23:33.328: INFO/dalvikvm-heap(2035): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.474MB for 3622512-byte allocation
10-06 16:23:33.422: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2035): GC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 91ms
10-06 16:23:33.422: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(2035): 14155776-byte external allocation too large for this process.
10-06 16:23:33.422: ERROR/(2035): VM won't let us allocate 14155776 bytes
10-06 16:23:33.422: DEBUG/skia(2035): --- decoder->decode returned false
10-06 16:23:33.422: WARN/dalvikvm(2035): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b170)
10-06 16:23:33.422: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2035): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-46 exiting due to uncaught exception
10-06 16:23:33.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2035): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
10-06 16:23:33.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
10-06 16:23:33.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:392)
10-06 16:23:33.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:405)
10-06 16:23:33.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at com.verdandsky.pecman.HttpClient.doGetImage(HttpClient.java:309)
10-06 16:23:33.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2035):     at com.verdandsky.pecman.ImageCache$1.run(ImageCache.java:79)
10-06 16:23:33.430: INFO/Process(1277): Sending signal. PID: 2035 SIG: 3
10-06 16:23:33.430: INFO/dalvikvm(2035): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
10-06 16:23:33.508: INFO/dalvikvm(2035): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Are you using the BitmapFactory and building the images from a byte[] in this case?

Comment: Sorry for a long time for the response. Not yet, do you think it's better for memory management? Now I'm using my own custom ImageCache, the problem is that the error once happens, on other file is runs smoothly.